# How to remove orphaned actions if you get not authorized access as uid1?

Tags: 7, drush

I get this error `1 orphaned actions (views_bulk_operations_archive_action) exist in the actions table. Remove orphaned actions`

But when I click `Remove orphaned actions` I get `You are not authorized to access this page.`.

And I'm logged in as UID1 user.

Can this be solved via drush?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Relative path `/admin/config/system/actions` shows a list of the actions available in the site.

If a site has orphaned actions, then relative path `/admin/config/system/actions/orphan` will provide the opportunity to remove them.

If you enter relative path `/admin/config/system/actions/orphan` and get redirected (automatically) to `/admin/config/system/actions/manage`, then that is an indication that there are no orphaned actions.

And if everything else fails, and you're willing to take the risk (+ a backup of your database first!), you might want to give it a try to edit the Drupal database using an SQL which looks like so:

```
delete from actions where aid = "views_bulk_operations_archive_action";
```